# How to get variable value from cURL

Tags: php, curl

```
 <?php
    $message=$_POST["msg"];

    echo $message;
    // create a new cURL resource
    $ch = curl_init();
    // set URL and other appropriate options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://.../pl1.php?
    m=$message");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    // grab URL and pass it to the browser
    curl_exec($ch);

    // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Above is the code iam using.anyone suggest me how do i get value of m in pl1.php

I am getting following error:
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

Comment: How about `$_GET['m']`. This is PHP 101. You should also [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the message before adding it to the url.

Comment: If we suppose that your code doesn't have any errors and it sends correctly the request this should work in `pl1.php` -> `$mMessage = $_GET['m'];` should work..

Comment: So, did any of the suggestions work for you? It would be nice with some feedback.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP variables passed as query string inside URL are accessible in [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) array.

In your case it will be `$_GET['m']`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
    <?php
    $message=$_POST["msg"];

    echo $message;

    // curl initialize
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set curl options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://.../pl1.php?
m=$message");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // execute request and return response
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    echo $output;

    // close cURL request
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

And to get that data on page pl1.php use $_GET['m'];

But, I believe sending data using curl with post method is better than get method.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the help its working.but it works only for one word i want to pass  sentence and due to space it is not taking complete message that i am passing.what to do to solve this issue ?

Comment: Its working finally.i used urlencode to send message.

Comment: Congratulations :)